# Unable to extend C: on Windows Server 2019

Tags: hard-drive, partition, windows-server-2019

I cant extend the C disk on a virtual machine from VMware enviroment.

[image]

I try diskpart and other partition tools. I read that maybe the cause is the reserved partition betwen C: and the unalocated space.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You are correct, the reason you can't extend the partition using the empty space is because there is already another partition (the recovery one) after it.

There are several third-party tools (free ones too) which can relocate the recovery partition to the end of the disk; after doing that, you'll be able to extend the system partition.

See also here: https://superuser.com/questions/1453790/how-to-move-the-recovery-partition-on-windows-10.

See also here, where a free tool is available: https://www.diskpart.com/windows-10/windows-10-move-recovery-partition-4348.html.
(Disclaimer: I'm not affiliated with this company in any way, it's simply one of the first results when Googling for this specific problem; good SEO on their part).